# Adding Autohotkey WinActivate to ControlSend

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to Open a minimized Notepad window regardless of which window is currently displayed using `ControlSend`. I wonder why the following code does not work?

```
F5:: WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad

WinGetTitle, Title, A

Controlsend,,{F5}, %Title%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiline remaps, you need to begin writing the code you want to execute starting on a new line after the key you want to remap.

So:

```
F5:: 
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad

WinGetTitle, Title, A

Controlsend,,{F5}, %Title%
return
```